# Making google maps responsive and resizing

Tags: html, css, google-maps

I'm trying to include a google maps embed on my page. I was able to get it to become responsive but I can't seem to be able to resize it to be smaller. The map just takes up way too much of the page and I want the map to be half the size in height. Is there a way to make it half the size in height? I've tried to reduce the height in the iframe but that doesn't seem to work.

```
<div class="googlemap-responsive">
   <iframe width='600' height='250' frameborder='0' scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src='https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d387144.0075834208!2d-73.97800349999999!3d40.7056308!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x89c24fa5d33f083b%3A0xc80b8f06e177fe62!2sNew+York%2C+NY!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1394298866288' ></iframe>
</div>
```

```
.googlemap-responsive{
    overflow:hidden;
    padding-bottom:56.25%;
    position:relative;
    height:0;
}
.googlemap-responsive iframe{
    left:0;
    top:0;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the structure you are using, the only thing you need to do is reduce the padding percentage.

Try something like:

```css
.googlemap-responsive {
   padding-bottom: 30%;
   // You can modify the percentage as your design requires.
}
```

Once you do that it occupies less height and adjusts responsively.

If you require the size to always be 200px, you can do the following:

```css
.googlemap-responsive {
   padding-bottom: 200px;
   // You can modify the percentage as your design requires.
}
```